# I've a WordPress installed on GCP & when I stopped and resumed the instance it is not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, custom-wordpress-pages, bitnami

I've created a free trial account on GCP and installed WordPress using bitnami. Now the problem is that it was very slow, so I stopped and resumed the VM Instance, now my website is not accessible. Please help.

Comment: Did the IP address change? Your question has no details, edit with more information.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. As John mentioned, we would need more information to debug this. Are all the services running after restarting the VM? `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status`. Does the machine have enough free RAM memory at that time? `free -m`.

Comment: Check the external IP you got after your VM was resumed (if it changed or no); if you still can't access your site just stop & start your VM.

Comment: Yes, the IP address did change post restart. After running the command this was the result. 
avirat_kulkarni@consultkay-wp-vm:~$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status
sudo: /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh: command not found

Also, really pardon me for my poor knowledge. I don't have very good or even fair knowledge of these. I followed some video tuts to set this up.

Comment: domain name  - https://consultkay.com/

and the ip address earlier was 35.185.209.105 and now it is 34.82.127.21

Comment: There is an update while troubleshooting the problem, I did check the DNS zone records. So I just replaced the old IP address with the new one, and it started working. Thank you all for the support!